# errorLineCount = 1 when no obvious errors during usage upload

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to send usage data to Microsoft Recommendation API. Here is my request:

```html
 POST /recommendations/v4.0/models/ccfb261a-ae96-4ae8-be43-15571fc47a66/usage?usageDisplayName=instasell  
 Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxx
 Content-Length: 409
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
 Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 User-Agent: InstaSell.ru
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 "19vu1oowsiupsrnnln7eu82ln,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "19vu1oowsiupsrnnln7eu82ln,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,9,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,134,2016/06/15T01:16:30,Click[\n]"
 "77,134,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,134,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,AddShopCart[\n]"
 "77,8,2016/06/15T01:16:30,Click"
```

But receive the following response:

```
{  
   "fileId":"c224766e-1e2a-405e-9367-37a0d36973d0",
   "processedLineCount":10,
   "errorLineCount":1,
   "importedLineCount":9,
   "errorSummary":[  

   ]
}
```

I don't see any differences in 10 lines. However microsoft api comlaints. Could you please help?

Comment: It seems that the last line of the request body miss the symbol `[\n]`. Could you check it whether it cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I finally understood the issue. It looks like I was trying to import usage about items unknown to API.

When I imported catalog, I filtered some of the invalid products/items. But usage data included them.

It's normal to reject invalid usage data during production. I was testing integration, so it should be perfectly clear why some usage points were rejected